# Swagger - Add Username/Login and use in Custom Header

Tags: c#, azure, swagger-ui

I have an azure mobile app api written in c#.

I have added Swagger using Nuget.

Swagger seems to work perfectly. But "out of the box" it allows a user to enter an API key in the top right of the swagger homepage... this value is then appended to all test calls with "?/api_key=xxxx"

I need to work out how to make swagger send this "key" as a custom header called "X-ZUMO-AUTH" in the body of the call.

Ideally, I would like to expand on this as well.

I have an "auth" api call which takes a username/password... It would be great if I could remove the "key" field on the UI with a username/password combination that calls my "auth" endpoint and uses the returned value I all subsequent calls to the api... Again as a custom header "X-ZUMO-AUTH"..

If I can achieve part 1 that would be great...

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 2):

See [Customize Authentication Header in SwaggerUI using Swashbuckle](http://stevemichelotti.com/customize-authentication-header-in-swaggerui-using-swashbuckle/) for a javascript solution.  If you are using MVC or a WebAPI, in the SwaggerConfig.cs as a part of `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnableSwagger(c => { })` add `c.OperationFilter<AddAuthorizationHeaderParameterOperationFilter>();`.

Then you can configure the by adding a class similar to:

```
public class AddAuthorizationHeaderParameterOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        var filterPipeline = apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.GetFilterPipeline();
        var isAuthorized = filterPipeline
                                         .Select(filterInfo => filterInfo.Instance)
                                         .Any(filter => filter is IAuthorizationFilter);

        var allowAnonymous = apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any();

        if (isAuthorized && !allowAnonymous)
        {
            if (operation.parameters == null)
            {
                operation.parameters = new List<Parameter>();
            }
            operation.parameters.Add(new Parameter
            {
                name = "Authorization",
                @in = "header",
                description = "access token",
                required = true,
                type = "string"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! - one observation is that you have to put [Authorize] on all controller actions not on the overall controller...

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom javascript that will be run and then it will do a call to a 3d party service and add it as a custom token.

There is a duplicate on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29275499/swagger-swashbuckle-oauth2-with-resource-owner-password-credentials-grant?rq=1) already.
You can try this [post](http://stevemichelotti.com/customize-authentication-header-in-swaggerui-using-swashbuckle/) as well.

This is how you add js:

```
c.InjectJavaScript(thisAssembly, "SwashbuckleCustomAuth.CustomContent.basic-auth.js");
```

And this is an example of one:

```
$('#explore').off();

$('#explore').click(function () {
   var key = $('#input_apiKey')[0].value;
   var credentials = key.split(':'); //username:password expected

$.ajax({
    url: "yourAuthEndpoint",
    type: "post",
    contenttype: 'x-www-form-urlencoded',
    data: "grant_type=password&username=" + credentials[0] + "&password=" + credentials[1],
    success: function (response) {
        var bearerToken = 'Bearer ' + response.access_token;

        window.swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add('Authorization', new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization('Authorization', bearerToken, 'header'));
        window.swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.remove("api_key");
        alert("Login successfull");
       },
       error: function (xhr, ajaxoptions, thrownerror) {
        alert("Login failed!");
       }
    });
});
```

P.S. Sorry, did not notice the other answer already had a reference to the same post. But there is a post on SO somewhere with more details.