# Is it possible to change the name of api_key in swagger?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to build asp.net mvc web api and also trying to use swagger for the first time.In my all request there is a parameter that is named as 'auth' and so using swagger i am entering a key to right-top of swagger page and pressing explore before testing the method and also i uncomment the code in swagger.config file as below.

```
 c.ApiKey("auth")
 .Description("API Key Authentication")
 .Name("auth")
 .In("query");
```

But still swagger taking the parameter name as 'api_key'.How can i change 'api_key' to 'auth' in swagger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I found the solution here at the end](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/398)

the solution is that the change in below function in index.html

```
function addApiKeyAuthorization() {
        var key = encodeURIComponent($('#input_apiKey')[0].value);
        if (key && key.trim() != "") {
            var apiKeyAuth = new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization("NAME OF PARAMETER", key, "query");
            window.swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add("api_key", apiKeyAuth);
            log("added key " + key);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to change the api_key directly, but you can use the UI js file to manipulate it fully the way you like. I have answered the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37349135/swagger-add-username-login-and-use-in-custom-header/37351865#37351865).

1) Add js file:

```
c.InjectJavaScript(thisAssembly, "SwashbuckleCustomAuth.CustomContent.basic-auth.js");
```

2) This is an example of the JS that will connect to a token server, get the API key by username/password and then add it as a header.

```
$('#explore').off();

$('#explore').click(function () {
   var key = $('#input_apiKey')[0].value;
   var credentials = key.split(':'); //username:password expected

$.ajax({
    url: "yourAuthEndpoint",
    type: "post",
    contenttype: 'x-www-form-urlencoded',
    data: "grant_type=password&username=" + credentials[0] + "&password=" + credentials[1],
    success: function (response) {
        var bearerToken = 'Bearer ' + response.access_token;

        window.swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add('Authorization', new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization('Authorization', bearerToken, 'header'));
        window.swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.remove("api_key");
        alert("Login successfull");
       },
       error: function (xhr, ajaxoptions, thrownerror) {
        alert("Login failed!");
       }
    });
});
```

So I imagine that you can use a way simpler js to change the name of the parameter as well.

This is not a simple change of name, but you can use that approach if it's not possible to do it easy way (which might be still possible of course).

Comment: thanks but i need to add it to url as parameter. I found the solution at the end

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of people who are using swagger:2.0. 
This should be set in the swagger.json file.

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "description": "API Documentation",
    "version": "1.0.2",
    "title": "my super service"
  },
  "basePath": "/my-super-services/api",
  "host": "example.com",
  "schemes": [
    "https",
    "http"
  ],
  "securityDefinitions": {
    "UserSecurity": {
      "type": "apiKey",
      "in": "header",       <----- set this to header or cookie or query
      "name": "X-Api-Key"   <----- you custom key goes here
    }
  },
```