# Swashbuckle Swagger UI OAuth2 GET token request unsupported_grant_type

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

#### Problems

- I am using `Swashbuckle 5.6.0` for ASP.NET Web Api 2 with OAuth2 token authentication. When I try to authorize a Controller action decorated with `[Authorize]` using the red exclamation mark button in SwaggerUI I receive the error

  > unsupported_grant_type
- Another problem seems to be that `SwaggerUI` makes a `GET` request to get the token. In `Postman` if I send a `POST` request to the token endpoint with the required `Content-Type` I get a valid token response. If I instead send a `GET` request in Postman it doesn't work either, I get

  > unsupported_grant_type

#### Researched so far

- Googling this error seems to indicate that the request to the Token endpoint needs a `Content-Type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`. However, I cannot find any way to set this `Content-Type` in Swashbuckle for token requests (I can set headers successfully for Controller actions using `IOperationFilters`).

#### Question

So, is there any way through Swashbuckle I can configure SwaggerUI to use POST with a specific Content-Type header when targeting the OAuth2 Token endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on whether you have a 1) real oAuth/OpenID implementation or 2) 'just' a token endpoint and [Authorize] attributes on controllers.

If you've got #2 then the [SO answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55117665/1586498) prompts for a username and password from the token endpoint of your choosing and set's the client_id from the apikey field (if required), and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31726613/1586498) allows you to paste in a Bearer token in the 'apikey' field.

If you've got #1 then you'll have to make sure you know your 'auth' and 'token' endpoints and mark them according to the [swashbuckle oauth2 documentation](https://github.com/OzBob/Swashbuckle#describing-securityauthorization-schemes)